# The WebAPI not working when sending data as json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm just started learn WebAPI,

When i'm trying to call my Api/TessterFunction and send data parameter as JSON ( **{"Test":"TEST"}** ) i got this response ***"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request"***,

***But*** when trying to call it and send the data as query string **(http ://localhost/myProject/myApi/TesterFunction?Test="TEST**") it's work and Get Done.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("TesterFunction")]
public HttpResponseMessage TesterFunction(string Test)
{
    try
    {
        myClass myObject= new myClass();

        if (myObject.myStordProcedure(CompanyCode))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done");
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "SP not executed");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: don't check in here check with sender. and do you  get null value  or do you get break point

Comment: i'm checked it using postman, i got this Message  "HTTP resource was found that matches the request" , when i'm put the breakpoint it's  didn't hit the method.

Comment: What's your controller's name? please describe your route config. your problem is an incorrect URL!

Comment: Many thanks dear @amirnorouzpour , the problem was i accept string not an object .see Jerdine answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work because your web api method only accepts string parameter.

What you could do is;

1. Add a class where the properties will be bound

```
public class ReceiveModel{
   public string Test {get;set;}
}
```

2. Then replace your web api method to use ReceiveModel parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("TesterFunction")]
public HttpResponseMessage TesterFunction(ReceiveModel model)
{
    // see the property here
    Console.WriteLine(model.Test);

    try
    {
        myClass myObject= new myClass();

        if (myObject.myStordProcedure(CompanyCode))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done");
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "SP not executed");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
    }

}
```